# elasticbeanstalk cli not working on new terminal

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

I installed ebcli using scripts method mentioned in following link:
https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup and it works like a charm, but when I open a new terminal and run `eb --version`, it says

> no command found

Can anyone tell me why it's showing that? It's just that it's working on the terminal I installed it in, but not the other terminal.

I tried to google the solution, but didn't come across anything relevant.

Comment: I am not familiar with AWS, but from "*it's working on the terminal I installed it in, but not the other terminal.*" I would suggest maybe installing it on the "other" terminal if you want it to work there?

Comment: what is the output of $which eb

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem.  That script installs eb into a virtual called .ebcli-virtual-env.  Look in your home directory for a .ebcli-virtual-env directory.  In there should be a bin/activate script.  Type source <full path to bin/activate> script.